# TypeScript user-defined type guard doesn't discriminate for union with optional property

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards, type-assertion

I have two types very similar except for an optional property

```
type Interval = { start: Date; end: Date; }
type IntervalOpenEnded = { start: Date; end?: Date; }
```

I want to be able to discriminate them so I've created an user-defined type guard

```
function isOpenEnded(interval: Interval | IntervalOpenEnded): interval is IntervalOpenEnded {
    return "end" in interval && interval.end != null;
}
```

For some reason, the compiler won't be able to discriminate this way

```
function thisDoesntWork(interval: Interval | IntervalOpenEnded) {
    if (isOpenEnded(interval)) {
        // interval here is still Interval | IntervalOpenEnded
        console.log(interval.end);
        throw new Error();
    }

    // this won't compile as the type of interval is "never"
    console.log(interval.end);
}
```

Discriminating outside of a user-defined type guard will work a bit better as it will compile

```
function thisWorks(interval: Interval | IntervalOpenEnded) {
    if ("end" in interval && interval.end != null) {
        // here interval is still Interval | IntervalOpenEnded
        console.log(interval.end);
        throw new Error();
    }

    // this will compile and interval is Interval | IntervalOpenEnded
    console.log(interval.end);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the type guard say `interval is Interval` ? Instead of `interval is IntervalOpenEnded` ?

Comment: The behavior is pretty much expected. since `IntervalOpenEnded` is a base type for `Interval`, if your type guard narrows to `IntervalOpenEnded` it will not exclude `Interval`

Comment: Nevermind, you're right, I'm an idiot

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. happens to all of us :)